# Incomplete response JSON body with flutter http.Request.send()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not sure what is going on with my function. I am trying to have a generic request function that I can use with any request method (GET, POST, etc...). Everything is working well, except for the POST response, it is missing data. I double checked what is expected to be returned and compared it with the response from Postman and my code. My code produces less data than expected and Postman.

Here is what I am doing

```
class HttpClientHandler {
  String baseUrl = 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  String path = '/posts';

  static const Map<String, String> defaultHeaders = {'': ''};
  static const Map<String, String> defaultBody = {'': ''};

  Future<dynamic> request(HttpMethod method,
      {Map<String, String> headers = defaultHeaders,
      Map<String, dynamic> body}) async {
    var uri = Uri.https(baseUrl, '$path');

    var request = http.Request(method.type, uri);
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.body = body.toString();

    var response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
      String rawData = await response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      return jsonDecode(rawData);
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

The caller simply does the following:

```
var _client = HttpClientHandler();
var data = await _client.request(HttpMethod.POST, body: {'title': 'foo', 'body': 'bar', 'userId': 1});
print(data);
```

The response I get is:

```
{id: 101}
```

The expected response is:

```
{
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar",
  "userId": "1",
  "id": 101
}
```

I am using `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` package. Is this a stream, transform, or headers issue?

Comment: Did you try printing `String rawData` to the console? What was it?

Comment: Yes I have. Same thing "{"id": 101}", missing everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong in my implementation, I didn't jsonEncode my request body. The test API I am using here replies the same request body it receives. Since I wasn't encoding the body correctly, it only was recognizing the first data being sent.

So, the fix is to change this line:

```
request.body = body.toString();
```

to this line:

```
request.body = jsonEncode(body);
```

Also, I ended up parsing the stream byte to string differently, from:

```
String rawData = await response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
```

To:

```
String rawData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
```